# Reading the Value of each row from the database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using ADO and use `CreateCmmand` and `CommandText` to write and run my SQL command which returns some rows if I run it in SQL server. But How in C# can I run it and loop through the values of the rows that it is returning? ( It only return one column in SQL server, but for example 80 rows) I need in C# to read the value of each of those rows and do some processing wit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It only return one column in SQL server, but for example 80 rows

**Problem :** you are only reading the value once [maybe using `if(reader.Read())`].

**Solution :** you need to Read the values untill `<SqlDataReader>.Read()` method returns `false` using `while(reader.Read())`.

Try This:

```
List<string> strNames=new List<string>();
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Name from mytable",con))
{    
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     strNames.Add(reader["Name"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
When you are in a `while(reader.Read())` loop you can access the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `SqlCommand` named `cmd` and your `SqlConnection` is named `connection`:

```
 connection.Open();
 using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

      while (rdr.Read()) {
            // Process current row
      }

 }
```

The `ExecuteReader`, returns a [`SqlDataReader`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)